# Deprecation error when trying to use SimplePie library in PHP

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I am working on news app and i need to parse current news from `RSS (Really Simple Syndication)`.

I have found [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) library to parse `RSS` feed easily.

First of all i have used this library directly on server with my `php code`.

```
<?php
// Make sure SimplePie is included. You may need to change this to match the location of autoloader.php
// For 1.0-1.2:
 
#require_once('../simplepie.inc');
// For 1.3+:
require_once('./php/autoloader.php');
 

// We'll process this feed with all of the default options.
$feed = new SimplePie("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=h&num=3&output=rss");

// Set which feed to process.
 
// Run SimplePie.
$feed->init();
 
// This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
$feed->handle_content_type();

    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
?>

    <div class="item">
      <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
      <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
    </div>

<?php 
        endforeach; 
?>
```

But i am running this file on my PC, i got following error:

```
Deprecated: Passing parameters to the constructor is no longer supported. Please use set_feed_url(), set_cache_location(), and set_cache_location() directly. in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\liveibl\php\library\SimplePie.php on line 640
```

I think this was occur because of PHP version but i do not think what can i do.

Please Help...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And what did you tried to solve this?

Comment: I have the impression that you haven't read the error message, since it explains what the problem is and what you have to do. Whatever, I've added an answer trying to explain in it detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says:

> Deprecated: Passing parameters to the constructor is no longer
>   supported. Please use set_feed_url(), set_cache_location(), and
>   set_cache_location() directly

The error is quite clear. You are not supposed to do this:

```
$feed = new SimplePie("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=h&num=3&output=rss");
```

(The **constructor** is the function that is called automatically when you create a class instance with the `new` operator, it that was your confusion.) The [documentation](http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie.html#___construct) says it explicitly:

> Previously, it was possible to pass in the feed URL along with cache
>   options directly into the constructor. This has been removed as of 1.3
>   as it caused a lot of confusion.

Instead, you have to do this:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
```

... and use the appropriate methods to provide the parameters. As the name suggests, [set_feed_url()](http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie.html#_set_feed_url) can be used to provide the feed's URL.